# How to execute timer functions in MATLAB GUI in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing, matlab-guide

I have designed a GUI using MATLAB GUIDE. I need to execute two timer functions in parallel. 
Let's say we have a timer and its function defined inside the GUI as follows:

```
handles.data_acq_tmr = timer(...
    'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
    'Period', 0.2, ...
    'Busymode','queue',...
    'TimerFcn', {@data_read, hObject});


function data_read(~,~,hObject,~)
handles = guidata(hObject);

% do some processing here

guidata(hObject,handles);
```

and the second timer as follows:

```
handles.dataproc_tmr = timer(...
    'ExecutionMode', 'singleShot', ...
    'StartDelay', 0,...
    'Busymode','queue',...
    'TimerFcn', {@data_proc, hObject});



function data_proc(~,~,hObject,~)
handles = guidata(hObject);

% do some other processing here

guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Is there any way to do it in MATLAB for instance using [Parallel Computing Toolbox](https://se.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing.html)?

Comment: Did you see [this post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98271) on MATLAB Answers or [this FEX submission](https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2014/08/01/time-parallel-for-parfor-loops/)?